# What if i do not fork my task and simply process in parallel using ForkJoinPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, forkjoinpool

I have been reading on Concurrency and Parallelism in JDK 7 i.e. ThreadPoolExecutor, ExecutorService & ForkJoinPool. I have already implemented ThreadPoolExecutor (to create controlled threads) & ExecutorService (For fixed threads) but now thinking of putting my processing in parallel using ForkJoinPool.

**My question initially is what if I just put my tasks to ForkJoinPool and do not actually fork further (as suggested to use RecursiveTask or RecursiveAction and use compute to fork for given threshold).**

My assumption is that processing in parallel for given no. of threads e.g. 4. would be faster than tasks processed concurrently. How far i will be achieving performance using **concurrency** & **parallelism**. Need your suggestions on it.

I will be extending my logic on ForkJoinPool in phases as program logic is complex

Comment: `ForkJoinPool` is a more of a strategy. It is useful if you have a single big task, which you could figure out portions that do not rely on state of other portions (i.e. independent). If you have 100 tasks that already do not affect one another in any way to begin with, you just need to dump these tasks into an executor.

Comment: But will it consume all cores on both cases, as in concurrent tasks it may not be using all cores but parallel tasks do. So my question remains there, even if i provide 1000 tasks to FJP and same to TPE which one is better regardless of breaking tasks further.

Comment: `FJP` adds an overhead computation due to the work stealing when breaking tasks. So if you have 1000 defined tasks, I guess `TPE` is better because he will process directly the tasks in the available threads.

Comment: computation overhead ? FJP also processes in given no. of threads, steal algorithm ensures that thread does not remain idle and steal task from anothers thread queue.

Comment: There is no work stealing with `TPE`.The work stealing is the way to `divide` task. From javaDoc for `FJP`, it say : A ForkJoinPool differs from other kinds of ExecutorService mainly by virtue of employing work-stealing.